# how can i resolve keychain access group issue without removing entitlements.plist file?

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect, provisioning-profile, entitlements

Here is the screenshot of the error

[image]

I have enabled keychain access group in capabilities and its added in Entitlements.plist

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
 <key>keychain-access-groups</key>
    <array>
        <string>L23874DF.com.your.appid</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I signed the archive with development provisioning profile and certificate and given it to the team that pushes it for appstore.

But I got the above error and I don't understand it has right appid prefix and bundle identifier and member center has no options to enable Keychain access group then in my eyes there should not be a problem.

the appstore certificate that they're using is from same appstore account so there shouldn't be a problem with app id.

App id is same for whole account irrespective of whether its development build or adhoc build or release build or appstore build

P.S
I had to remove my entitlements.plist and resign the app with same dev cert and provision to make archive and send to them and it got published to appstore without any problem

somebody explain me whats wrong with this behaviour ? I am still confused

Comment: You recheck if the APP Groups (in apple dev portal) have any APP ID and are those used in the AppID that are used to create the provisionign profile. You need to add all those to your entitlement.plist.

Comment: Are you resigning the app with Xcode or shell script , let me know so can assist you accordingly. I suspect the profile that is embedded in the IPA is not having those entitlements as listed in the xarchive.

Comment: Open the archive extract the app using Ctrl_click and show package contents and see what is the value in the archived-entitlement.xccent file and also the info.plist file if you can pass here.

Comment: Also, run the command over the terminal for the provisioning profile in the app with name embedded.provisioningprofile $security  cms -D -i <profile path here> and validate if its matching to the entitlement and any other TEAM ID and all entries

Comment: I am confused....

Comment: You should ensure that the target and its provisioning profile have same entitlements matching to make right ipa. To open provisioning profile on terminal as text file just enter the command as my first comment and it will show you the XML of the profile file. See the entitlements tag inside and it should match with the entries as mentioned in your entitlements. Plist